# Wordpress Site - Too Many Redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm runnning a .ca website, and my site has too many redirects.

It goes from

```
http://mysite.ca to
https://wwww.mysite.ca to
https://wwww.mysite.ca/
```

here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^MYSITE\.ca [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.MYSITE.ca/$1 [L,R=301]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Try clearing your browser caches.

Comment: that didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **ssl certificate** add the following code to your **wp-config.php** file.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

see the [this post](https://www.sharpten.com/blog/2018/01/17/wordpress-stuck-many-redirects-error-loop-using-ssl.html)